# react native gifted chat with memo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gifted-chat

is there a way to put memo with gifted chat and rerender only when new message added ?

```
      <GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        renderMessage={() => }
        onSend={messages => onHandleSend(messages)}
        onPressAvatar={handleNavigateToUser}
        renderActions={renderAction}
        renderChatFooter={renderChatFooter}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
        text={image && ' '}
        alwaysShowSend={true}
        locale='DE'
        user={{
          _id: 1,
        }}
      />
```

if I set a any state all rerenders so that bad with a lot of images

Comment: can you share with us the `renderMessage` function?

Comment: @DarkSide77 I removed I dont use it anymore